# Backup and Restore of Machine Account (Active Directory)

Tags: windows, active-directory, accounts, reinstall

I have an XP Workstation which is member of an AD Domain. I have to reinstall Windows XP on the machine.
After that I should ask the Domain Admin to re-join the machine to the domain. Is there any way of backing-up an restore the domain account on the machine to avoid re-joining to the AD domain?

Thanks

Comment: By "machine account", do you mean the user profile?

Comment: No, I mena machine account. For every machine who is part of a Domain, the Domain Controller has an account named <MACHINENAME>$ which basically is like a Shared Secret for Kerberos Auth

Comment: Just have the AD administrator delegate you to be able to add machines to a particular OU in the domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No

Answer (score 0):

If you're re-installing, just remove the old machine account and re-add the machine.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that because I don't have the privileges to join a machine to the domain.

Comment: If you don't have those privileges, how in the hell did you think you were going to be restoring part of AD? The machine account is in AD, not on the machine in question.